# introducing new parameters to logistic regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic

I have a ML model that uses logistic regression with normalization. To train & evaluate it  I use a stratified dataset which consists of tens thousands records aggregated from some historical data with encoding for categorical data. The whole dataset has 9 parameters.

But now there is a need to add new parameter, which did not exist in the previous dataset.

What should I do with the old data? Should I wait for accumulation of the data with new parameter and train the model again but with it? Can somehow use old data but introduce for it new parameter with the default value? Should I wait and see how new parameter affect the system and probably only then try to introduce some default value for old dataset?

Comment: Can you tell us more details, like what is the "system" that is affected? In what way? What is the new parameter representing? ...